# Composite key on phone and email

Tags: sql, database-design

In table `User` records are identified by a combination of `email` and `phone`:

| id | email | phone |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NULL | 123 |
| 2 | a@gmail.com | NULL |

Each id represents a unique user. Suppose a new record comes in as:

| email | phone |
| --- | --- |
| a@gmail.com | 123 |

I already have the same email and phone so I'm merging id's (drop 1st and 2nd record and generate id 3 with proper email and phone). Then I update dependent tables' foreign keys (from id 1 to 3 and id 2 to 3).

I have many tables using this id as foreign key. To update the user id in all these tables is causing performance issues. Is there a better approach that avoids updating foreign keys? I am looking for a better data model.

Answer (score 2):

You say that each row in the table represents a user. And a user is identified by email + phone.

- This means that you can have two users with the same email account, as long as they have different phone numbers. This sounds reasonable; co-workers may share an email account.
- And you can have two users with the same phone as long as they have different email accounts. This sounds reasonable, too; a family shares their home phone.

As for the database, you seem to have a good table for this. Your user table has an ID, so you can always use this in your database to identify the user. And you have the email address and the phone number in the table, and you can create a unique constraint on the combination. Seems fine to me.

Now you show a scenario where you have an entry for an email account where the phone number is NULL. This means you want to allow users with unknown phone numbers and identify them by their email account only. (This means you would take those co-workers to be the same user, as long as they only contact you by email.) And a new record comes in with the same email account and an additional telephone number.

How do you classify this event? Is this the same user, and you are getting to know their phone number? Then update the row with the phone number. Or is this a new user that you can tell from the existing one? Then add this new user. I see no case where you would delete the existing user, because this is no scenario where a user cancelled your services.

Think this through. This is all the advice I can give you here. Think about the data you are getting and whether this suffices to recognize a user. Do you really want to allow users without a phone number in your database? Maybe you want to issue user numbers that every user must use to uniquely identify themselves, so you won't have to guesstimate by email and phone. Having registered users with a unique number or unique user name is the common practice to deal with users in a system.

### UPDATE

According to your comment below, all this is about guessing. ("We may only receive phone or only email or both or none")

In that case you do want to allow nulls in both phone or email. There would even be the Unknown user who has neither phone nor email. For the unique constraint that would mean that you either replace NULL with a string, e.g. `'##UNKNOWN##'` or create a unique function index on `(COALESCE(email, '##UNKNOWN##'), COALESCE(phone, '##UNKNOWN##'))`, if your DBMS allows that.

As to your scenario: You must again think about how to treat the new record.

- Is this the moment where you get to know the user's phone? In that case you would update the user row with the phone number and thus treat all existing data with this email and without phone to be that user. And if new data comes in with this email and without a phone number, you'd assign this data to this user, too.
- Or do you want the two to be considered two different users, one user where the data contains both email and phone and another user where the data contains just the email address? In tha case you wuld insert the new user. And with new data coming in you would look at the phone in order to decide which of the two users you want to assign this data to.

Again: You don't want to delete any row in either scenario. Either update or insert.

Comment: Okay then let me tell you where this data is coming from. These data is coming from snowplow  (https://snowplow.io/) which provide first party customer data. And we want to identify the users behaviour. We may only receive phone or only email or both or None. We are trying to do user stitching (https://snowplow.io/blog/identity-stitching-with-snowplow/) which will tell us what are known users, and based on that we can target the customers.

Comment: Okay, I have updated my answer. You should put the additional information (that both email and phone can be null and you want to guess the user from the data) into your request, because it is essential for giving an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 2):

create new tables for email and phone and link them to user

```
CREATE TABLE Email (
    email_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user_id INT,
    email VARCHAR(255),
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES User(id)
);

CREATE TABLE Phone (
    phone_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user_id INT,
    phone VARCHAR(15),
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES User(id)
);
```

work on this two table to get proper email and phone based on userId

you will have only one userId and you will not have to update other tables

Answer (score 0):

You probably should enforce that email (or phone) be mandatory.

A user creates new user:
id 1, no phone, a@mail.com

then he wants to create a new user:
if the email is null, you dont allow it.
if the email is already present, you can ask if the user wants to add the phone to user id 1, if not, he needs to input another mail.
if he says ok, then you update user 1 to have this new phone.

Comment: We can't enforce user. They are free to use anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can take one of the ids as a reference point and then half of the ids will need no updates. For example:

| id | email | phone |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NULL | 123 |
| 2 | a@gmail.com | NULL |

here you don't need to insert a new record. You could take record with id = 2 and merge records whose user_id = 1 with those whose user_id = 2. This way, in our case you will only need to resolve the references with user_id = 1 via merging them into references with user_id = 2, without adding a third record into the problem. You still have to do some merging, but the number of merging you need to do will already be halved.

Next, it would be great if you would automate the merging as well. Figure out what exactly you needed to do to the record with id = 1 in order to merge all references from other tables to the user table having a user_id = 1 into their pair with user_id = 2 and then you will be able to do similar merge to arbitrary future ids.

And then, instead of inserting (email, phone), you could implement a stored procedure that checks whether that email and/or phone already exists. If only one such record exists, then you do not even need to do a refactoring. Instead, you just update the null email or phone to the value you have successfully received. If two such records exist, then you need to perform such an update.

But if you have some automated steps for the update, then you just call the corresponding stored procedure and pass the two ids in order to properly merge them.

And, if both the email and phone are new / null, then you do a proper insert.

Answer (score 0):

I think the proper way is to create a middle table-

UserDetails -- UserStaticIds -- OtherTables

so UserDetails can have: UserId (PK), Email, Phone

then UserStaticIds can have: UserStaticId (PK), UserId (FK to UserDetails)

and Other tables should have: Some Fields, ... , UserStaticId (FK to UserStaticId)

--

I suggest to set Unique Index for Email, and for Phone in UserDetails

and of course to set Unique Index for UserId in UserStaticIds

--

In this way, you can keep your algorithm, without having to replace key in all other tables

Comment: Yes, much better approach. Here we just need to modify the UserStaticIds or surrogate table if there is any change in IDs. The only thing that will affect is some performance issue because of extra join to the User table via UserStatic table

Comment: yes, the performance will be impact, however a PK to Unique Index usually keeps the performance high